# Agrupar Filas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, transact-sql

alguien me podría ayudar con esta consulta? necesito adjuntar esos dos NUMEROD que se repiten '00693750' y dejar solo una informacion alineada con los dos montos ([0005],[0002]) en una sola FILA. Gracias!![image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si es lo que estas buscando:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.NUMEROD
    ,(SELECT R5.[0005] FROM Resultados R5 WHERE R5.[0005] IS NOT NULL AND R5.NUMEROD = R.NUMEROD) AS [0005]
    ,(SELECT R2.[0002] FROM Resultados R2 WHERE R2.[0002] IS NOT NULL AND R2.NUMEROD = R.NUMEROD) AS [0002]

FROM  Resultados R WHERE NUMEROD IN (SELECT R.[NUMEROD] FROM Resultados R GROUP BY R.NUMEROD HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

El resultado que obtuve fue:

```
NUMEROD         0005          0002
00693750    332000.000        25.000
```

Básicamente es una consulta donde si te das cuenta el FROM de abajo es una tabla que creo con una consulta que busca devolver los NUMEROD que tengan dos registros.  Estoy asumiendo que [0005] si esta null el [0002] no lo está y viceversa.

Los nombres de R5 y R2 los coloque con esos numero haciendo referencia a los campos [005] y [0002].  Si no entiendes algo, preguntame.

Espero te sirva.